# Can Borg survive in outer space without an environment suit?

Tags: star-trek, borg

This question is prompted from the scene in the film First Contact, when the Borg are outside the Enterprise creating the transmitter to communicate with the Borg of that time period, on the main deflector dish, they are working on that transmitter for some time, at least a few hours, yet they have no air and no protection for their biological cells to the extremes of space.

How did they survive? Borg are obviously very adaptable to many situations and environments, but they are part biological, and as such that biological part of them still needs the basics for survival: warmth (not the freezing cold that is the vacuum of space) and presumably some kind of atmosphere (be that nitrogen/oxygen or whatever), not the vacuum of space.

The nanotechnology could repair any damage I'm sure, but could it *continually* repair such extremes of damage such that Borg could survive for extended periods of time outside of a starship?

Comment: Empirically the answer would seem to be "Yes".

Comment: "Yes" as in "intentionally done this way", or "yes" as in "the director/writer just didn't think about it?" :)

Comment: Well, that is now an entirely different question.

Comment: Actually, I've read that it's not freezing in space. In fact, vacuum is a pretty good heat insulator (the only heat loss is via radiation), so it'd be quite some time before it got cold. The main problems for humans is low (no) air pressure and high radiation.

Comment: @Vilx:  Well, space *is* freezing, but it's also a good insulator, so *you* wouldn't be immediately.  If the explosive decompression doesn't kill you, hypoxia and blood vessel ruptures would be your immediate problems.  Hypothermia would take longer.

Comment: @Tynam: No, space itself isn't freezing.  Temperature is an attribute of matter; a vacuum has no temperature.

Comment: @Keith: I was being colloquial; you know what I meant. 'Temperature' is not a good word in this context. A vacuum has no temperature, but a Borg in a vacuum does have an equilibrium temperature.  (If we nitpick, space isn't a vacuum, even away from stars, but of course you'd never notice. Most of the interstellar medium is technically *hot*, but if you sat in it *you'd* experience a chilly 4K or so.)  Nevertheless, NASA put those heaters in the spacesuits for a reason.  Out of direct sunlight the equilibrium temperature of an object in planetary orbit is *not warm*.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Space isn't a _pure_ vacuum. It has a few particles flating around in it.

Comment: @Everyone - you seem to get my idea anyway. :)

Comment: @Shufflepants - Ermm, aren't you arguing to the wrong person? :) Also, it's been 7 years since this question was posted...

Comment: @Vilx- Yes, tagged the wrong person. Should have tagged KeithThompson. As for the question's age, I generally just browse Hot Network questions and sometimes their related questions. I didn't even look at when this was posted. Guess I'll just delete and repost with the appropriate tag since it won't let me edit :p

Comment: @KeithThompson Temperature may typically be a feature of matter, but there's still a sense that we can talk about the temperature of the vacuum. Conduction is not the only way heat is transferred. There is also exchange of heat through black body radiation. The main way something freezes in space is because it is radiating all of its heat in the form of infrared radiation but the things around it are not radiating an equal amount back because the radiation from the CMB corresponds to a temperature that is ~3-4K. So, this is the way in which the vacuum of space has a temperature of 3-4K

Comment: @KeithThompson And in fact, there was a period a few hundred million years after the big bang where the universe was sparse enough that most of space was still a vacuum, but the temperature you'd experience from the CMB would have left space downright comfortable, at least temperature wise.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would presume that the borg technology could create a barrier around each body, some kind of personalized forcefield, to keep it at the correct temperature and protect it from vacuum.  As a result, there would be no need to repair any damage.

The nanites would also be able to convert carbon dioxide to oxygen (storing the extra carbon atoms somewhere) directly in the lungs, eliminating the need to breathe.

Comment: I figured they probably could have a forcefield, you just don't see anything like that in the film - probably because the director couldn't be bothered adding the extra special effects in, I guess. Nice point about CO2 conversion to Oxygen.

Comment: I presumed that it would be a field of some kind because the Borg used personal fields in TNG. It wouldn't necessarily be visible though - I would presume that it was drawn in skin tight.

Comment: And though it's probably b-canon, the Animated Series has EXACTLY this kind of force-field in the very first episode.

Comment: If they don't need to breathe, there is probably no need to "protect them from vacuum."  See [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8521/would-a-humans-blood-suddenly-boil-or-eyes-body-explode-in-a-vacuum)

Comment: That article mostly discusses short term effects, not what would be necessary for them to continue to both live and work (physical labor) for hours. The force field would a) maintain pressure - just enough, not a full atmosphere; b) insulate against cold and heat as the objects that they will be working with will be very cold or very hot (on the order of -200 to +200C); c) prevent atmosphere loss - they won't need much, but will need some.

Comment: as I recall, we get to see borg on the outer hull of the Enterprise E during "First Contact".  Their implants seem to take care of the vacuum, cold and radiation very well.

Comment: This answer seems like speculation. Do you have quotes from canon sources to support your answer?

Answer (score 32):

There is an episode of Star Trek: Voyager (I think when they find 7of9) where they explore this question.  Based on that episode they do say Borg can survive with out an atmosphere for a period but will need to return to an oxygenated environment after about 24 hrs.

Comment: best answer yet.

Comment: @chcuk - just wanted to say thanks for this answer. Alas, I can only accept one answer as 'correct', and although your answer may be technically correct, it doesn't answer the "how" part of my question, only "yes they can".

Comment: I understand completely @NickShaw was planning to update my answer as soon as I could pull up the specific episode I mention.

Answer (score 4):

The Borg adapt, and the Borg create specialized drones for specialized tasks.

In episodes of TNG we see the Borg can create personal force fields to protect themselves from hazards, and in I, Borg Hugh explains that drones have specialized pieces or appendages or modules to enable them to perform specialized tasks efficiently.

I would say the Borg outfitted drones with particular modules and technology to perhaps create a personal force field and oxygen producing appendages.