# Why was Seven of Nine upset at Borg drones being ejected into space, when they can survive in a vacuum?

Tags: star-trek, borg, star-trek-first-contact, star-trek-picard, seven-of-nine

In Star Trek *Picard* season one Borg drones are ejected into space. Seven of Nine seems upset at this. But what's the big deal, as Star Trek *First Contact* has shown that Borg drones can survive in vacuum? All she has to do is beam them back on board and they'll be fine.

Comment: Active Borg with shielding, presumably. Whereas these are inactive Borg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Borg survive in outer space without an environment suit?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14942/can-borg-survive-in-outer-space-without-an-environment-suit)

Comment: @F1Krazy it's a stretch but a good suggestion. Maybe we can wait to see what the OP thinks...

Comment: First Contact clearly shows borg can survive vacuum so I don't know what the point of that other question is, and it doesn't explain why Seven was upset.

Comment: @sno The top-voted answer on that question explains that the Borg in *First Contact* were only in a vacuum for a few hours, and that *Voyager* had already established they can only survive in a vacuum for 24 hours or so before needing to replenish their oxygen. That would explain why Seven of Nine was upset: the Borg drones wouldn't have died *immediately*, but they would die *eventually*. Perhaps I should make this an answer?

Comment: @F1Krazy yeah I think so! The linked question has nothing about Seven of Nine. Who knows maybe she had a bad experience with the vacuum of space once and just doesn't like it despite being survivable...?

Comment: Humans can survive in a vacuum for a limited time too. Do you want to try? :D

Comment: So you see people vented into space, to drift for eternity. Fun, hm?

Comment: Wouldn't you be upset if you witnessed people being thrown overboard into the middle of the Atlantic,  even if you knew they could swim (for a bit)

Answer (score 23):

According to the top-voted answer on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14942/can-borg-survive-in-outer-space-without-an-environment-suit), *Star Trek: Voyager* establishes that Borg drones can only survive in the vacuum of space temporarily, not indefinitely. The question itself notes that the Borg in *First Contact* were only in a vacuum for a few hours.

I believe the episode referred to in that answer is S4E1, "Scorpion, Part II". At one point in that episode, Seven of Nine and a group of other Borg drones are in the cargo bay, attempting to create a quantum singularity. Chatokay depressurises the cargo bay and all but Seven of Nine are ejected into the vacuum of space.

[Memory Alpha's article on the episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpion,_Part_II_(episode)) notes:

> Seven of Nine, having emerged from the Jefferies tube, and able to survive in a vacuum **for a limited time** as Borg drones are capable of doing...

When I have more time I will try and find a clip of the episode and get a more direct quote.

So Seven of Nine's upset reaction in *Picard* seems to be a combination of two factors:

1. The ejected Borg would not have been killed *immediately*, but they would have died *eventually*.
2. Seven of Nine knows first-hand how unpleasant it is to be ejected like that.

Comment: Oh, looks like I guessed right about SoN having a bad run in with a vacuum!

Comment: Heh. I just watched that episode last night.

Comment: @FreeMan There's always somebody who watched any episode last night

Comment: It's also possible that drones don't normally carry an oxygen supply and did so specifically for their mission with the deflector.